# Password to join xmrpool

Tags: mining

Question might seem silly, but I'm so lost on this part! Here's what happened: I followed [this tutorial](https://jonathanmh.com/how-to-mine-monero-xmr-with-your-cpu-on-linux/) to start mining. Everything is going fine, so I wanted to log in XMRPool. I read the "Get started page", but I still can't figure out which username and password are mine.

Coinsidering the fact that I used this line to start mining:

```
sudo ./minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://MININGPOOL:PORT -u WALLET_ADDRESS -p MINER_NAME
```

my username should be `WALLET_ADDRESS` and my password `MINER_NAME` but it's not working. I tried a lot of thing, added +difficulty to username, also :email to password but it's still not working. Do you guys have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "login" to pool per say. Username is almost always your wallet address. Password can usually literally be anything, something you can use to identify which of your machines is mining. Most pools allow you to use the format `anything:you@example.com` so you can get alerts and such like at your email address.

Comment: Ohh I see. I tried this. Then the password is only the email!
Quite tricky, but working, thanls :)